# Is there any evidence what happened right after the end of Snatch?

Tags: ending, snatch

At the end of the 2000 movie "Snatch," what happens next is left ambiguous.

> Avi boards a plane to London to go to Doug's place and purchase (or steal?) the diamond presented by Turkish and Tommy.  However, his passport is stamped "The End" when he lands in London.

It's not clear if the diamond is actually purchased after that, or if it's stolen with the presenters killed, or if everybody involved is arrested.

Is there any "word of God" evidence (comments from the movie's creators) or mentions in the script of what happens next?

---

On [this forum](https://forums.anandtech.com/threads/what-happens-in-the-end-of-snatch.1208471/#post-9762932), a random internet person™ claimed it's stated in the screenplay:

> I'm right. (this is my favorite movie ever and I bought the screenplay and it has a section on this after the regular play)
>
> However, I am not going to tell you.

And [this fan theory on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/FanTheories/comments/3gygu3/why_snatch_ends_like_it_does_spoilers_by_the/) presents sensible arguments why everyone gets arrested next.

But I would like to know if there is definite canonical evidence, OR strong supporting evidence in the movie, what happened next.